# Customizing relevant scoring in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I have been going through the docs of Elasticsearch, and was curious about the relevance scoring fundamentals used in Elasticsearch. So in ES basically three factors—term frequency, inverse document frequency, and field-length norm—are used to calculate the relevant score of a particular document.

Now given the condition I don't want my result to be influenced by term frequency and field-length. How can I achieve it, I read it somewhere that for that you need to provide **"not_analyzed"** analyzer to the field. But doing that will defeat lot of my functionalities, so the question here arises how to prevent my result being influenced by term frequency and field-length with still using my custom analyzer or other analyzers.

Answer (score 0):

been looking around a bit as well. But the only thing that I can think of is using the constant score function:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/ignoring-tfidf.html

Also this guy gives a good description how you could create your own similarity algorithm. As he describes himself, this should be the last thing you try, but it is not really hard.
http://stefansavev.com/blog/custom-similarity-for-elasticsearch/

Answer (score 0):

One feature that you could use is the `constant_score` [query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-constant-score-query.html). For instance, if you wanted to detect when a particular set of terms appear in a text, regardless of the amount of times that they appear and the length of the documents, you could wrap a filter or a query with `constant_score` and assign a fixed score to the documents that match them.

For instance, if you wanted to look for documents related to cars that have the terms "crankshaft", "cylinder" and "engine", and you'd like to give more weight to the term "cylinder" than to "crankshaft", and more weight to "crankshaft" than to "engine", you could use a query like this:

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                { 
                    "constant_score": {
                        "boost": 3,
                        "query": { "match": { "fulltext": "cylinder" }}
                    }
                },
                { 
                    "constant_score": {
                        "boost": 2,
                        "query": { "match": { "fulltext": "crankshaft" }}
                    }
                },
                { 
                    "constant_score": {
                        "query": { "match": { "fulltext": "engine" }}
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, you would be matching documents with all of this terms, but you could control the importance of each term by assigning your own score to each of them by means of the parameter `boost`.

Note that in this case, the "[Coordination factor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/practical-scoring-function.html#coord)", which is the score that gives more weight to documents that have a higher percentage of the queried terms is also taken into account.